# Connection refused while accessing REST Api from Go client when both client and api are on same docker container

Tags: go, docker-compose

I am super new to docker and Go. I've created a client app in Go which test an REST API. The API is provided as part of docker image. I am supposed to add tests in client app and make my client app available as part of same docker-compose.yml.

On local I am able to run `go test -v ./... -cover` and all tests are able to access api `http://localhost:8095/v1/organisation/accounts`

When I run `docker compose up` I get error in below screenshot.

Somehow the client app is not able to access api url within container but its able to access it from my host laptop

Any advice will be very helpful on how to get this done. My instructions for this task are that test written in client app against the api endpoint should run as part of docker-compose.yml file.

[image: Docker Compose Error]

I added new Dockerfile for me client app as below and then included it in docker-compose.yml.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine

ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

WORKDIR /build

# Copy and download dependency using go mod
COPY go.mod .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

WORKDIR /build/accountsapi

RUN go test ./... -cover
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  # App Service
  app:
    # Configuration for building the docker image for the service
    build:
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: 
      - accountapi
  accountapi:
    image: cooltech/accountapi:v1.0.0-50-g48935
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
      - vault
    environment:
  - PSQL_USER=root
  - PSQL_PASSWORD=password
  - PSQL_HOST=postgresql
  - PSQL_PORT=5432
  - STACK_NAME=accountapi
  - DATABASE-HOST=postgresql
  - DATABASE-SSL-MODE=disable
  - DATABASE-USERNAME=api_user
  - DATABASE-PASSWORD=XXX
ports:
  - 8095:8080
...more services
```

Here is sample test and actual method

```
func TestGetAccountByIdExpectsNoAccount(t *testing.T) { 
    // act
    resp := GetAccountById(getUUID())

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    //assert
    if status := resp.StatusCode; status != http.StatusNotFound {
        t.Errorf("handler returned wrong status code: got %v want %v",
            status, http.StatusOK)
    }
}

const Baseurl = "http://localhost:8095/v1/organisation/accounts"
func GetAccountById(id string) *http.Response {

    var url = fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", Baseurl, id)
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    return resp
}
```

Comment: How does your tests looks like? Do you need the service be running port 8095?

Comment: @Rengas No, it doesn't have to on 8095 within the container. It can be 8080 or any other. My test is just simply calling the API Get or Post Method. Added actual method and Test Method above

Comment: when you do this http.Get(url), the test expects to have service running. when you docker build you are just building the image not really running the service. 
So the test will fail.

Comment: that make a lot of sense now. Thank you so much. Then how can I run these tests as part of docker?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the issue after **@Rengas** pointed out in comments that I am trying to run the test before my API service is up which is part of docker-compose. So I removed the
`go test -v ./...` from my Dockerfile and added it as part of docker-compose which looks like below now

```
accountapitesting:
    build:
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    command: go test -v ./...
    depends_on: 
      - accountapi
```